# Explanation for function preferring

Tags: c++, scope, overloading

Let's say I have the following program:

```
template <class X> void foo(X val) { }

template <> void foo<double>(double val) { }

class obj
{
public:
   void callFoo() { foo(7.3); }
private:
   void foo(int val) { }
};

int main()
{
    obj o;
    o.callFoo();
}
```

Why the `foo(int val)` is chosen?
Doesn't it supposed to be the `foo<double>(double val)`?
I thought maybe the class scope caused the `foo(int val)` to be called.

Comment: By the way, this is *not* overloading, as you have the question tagged. Overloading would be if you had defined a second `foo` function as a member of the `obj`, but taking a different parameter (e.g., a `double` instead of an `int`). The code you've shown here is actually *hiding* or *shadowing* the functions.